# eigenvalues of a matrix via determinant and trace

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I came across a relationship for the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$:

$$1 + \text{det} A > | \text{trace}A|.$$

I'm not sure what the assumptions for this relationship are. Is it for any real matrices?

Thanks for your clarifications.

Comment: It cannot hold for any real matrix. The inequality does not hold if the eigenvalues of a real $2\times 2$ matrix are $\frac{1}{2}$ and $2$, for instance.

Comment: It doesn't even hold for the identity matrix. It does hold for any anti-symmetric matrix though, but it isn't very interesting in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your idea is biased, in fact, we can choose a matrix satisfy $|A|=0$ and $|trace(A)|>1$, right? For example, $A=[1 ~1;1 ~1]$.